# Searching for two matches in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm looking for a way to match two terms in a single string. For instance if I need to match both "foo" and "bar" in order for the string to match and be printed, and the string is "foo 121242Z AUTO 123456KT 8SM M10/M09 SLP02369", it would not match. But if the string was "foo 121242Z AUTO 123456KT 8SM bar M10/M09 SLP02369", it would match and then go on to be printed. Here's the code that I have currently but I am a bit stuck. Thanks!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Cwd;

my @folder = ("/d2/aschwa/archive_project/METAR_data/");

open(OUT , '>', 'TEKGEZ_METARS.txt') or die "Could not open $!";

print OUT "Date (YYYYMMDD), Station, Day/Time, Obs Type, Wind/Gust (Kt), Vis (SM),
Sky, T/Td (C), Alt, Rmk\n";

print STDOUT "Finding METAR files\n";

my $criteria = sub {if(-e && /^/) {  
    open(my $file,$_) or die "Could not open $_ $!\n"; 
      my $dir = getcwd;
        my @dirs = split ('/', $dir);
         while(<$file>) {
           $_ =~ tr/\015//d;
             print OUT $dirs[-1], ' ', $_ if /foo?.*bar/;
               } 
             } 
            };

find($criteria, @folder);
close OUT;
print STDOUT "Done Finding Station METARS\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with positive look-ahead for both strings:

```
print OUT $dirs[-1], ' ', $_ if m/(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simple:

```
perl -ne'print if /foo.*bar/'
```

If you want process more files from some directory use `find`

```
find /d2/aschwa/archive_project/METAR_data/ -type f -exec perl -MFile::Spec -ne'BEGIN{$dir = (File::Spec->splitdir($ARGV[0]))[-2]} print $dir, ' ', $_ if /foo.*bar/' {} \; > TEKGEZ_METARS.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $string1 = "foo 121242Z AUTO 123456KT 8SM M10/M09 SLP02369";
my $string2 = "foo 121242Z AUTO 123456KT 8SM bar M10/M09 SLP02369";  

my @array = split(/\s+/, $string2);

my $count = 0;
foreach (@array){
     $count++ if /foo/;
     $count++ if /bar/;

}

print join(" ", @array), "\n" if $count == 2;
```

This will print for `$string2`, but not for `$string1`